# Cordova Phonegap File plugin FileWriter cordova.file

Tags: android, file, cordova, filewriter

Why this works :

```
myFile1 = "myReadme.txt";

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(myFile1, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    alert("good");                      
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("Error");
}
```

**and that doesn't work ?**

```
myFile2 = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "myReadme.txt";

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(myFile2, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    alert("good");                      
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("Error");
}
```

**Can we not use cordova.file.dataDirectory or cordova.file.externalRootDirectory or externalDataDirectory for Android ?**

Thank you

Comment: According to the documentation found on https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md this should work on Android. But be aware that `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` points to the data directory on an external device. Maybe the file you are getting is not in the correct file system.

Comment: 1) According to the documentation found on this should work on Android => ok
2) But be aware that cordova.file.externalDataDirectory points to the data directory on an external device. => yes, but I tried cordova.file.dataDirectory or cordova.file.externalRootDirectory too and its doesn't work

Comment: 3) Maybe the file you are getting is not in the correct file system => Can you explain, please ?

Comment: You are using getFile(). Which reads the file from the system. So the myReadme.txt should be in the right directory already to be able to read it. I also assume that myFile2 and myFile1 are a typo here on stackoverflow? You are declaring myFile2 and using myFile1 in getFile()

Comment: You didn't say *how* it didn't work.

Comment: @Raymond : It doesn't work because in "myFile2" example, I would like to create a file in a folder in a Device. When I display "function fail(error) { alert(error)} ==> I obtain : Error 5 <=> ENCODING_ERR and the file is not created. Is it clear ?

Comment: @ Mark : "You are declaring myFile2 and using myFile1 in getFile()" => yes, it's just a copy/paste mistake but the problem is not here ;-)

Comment: @MarkVeenstra : "You are using getFile(). Which reads the file from the system. So the myReadme.txt should be in the right directory already to be able to read it" => Yes, you're Right ! We have to check or Create the folder before to check or Create a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna try to answer with this issue (**but I'm sure we can to do better ?** )

First, when I plug my device to my computer the tree path is about like that :

- MyFile1.txt
- MyApplication

  - MyFiles
  - MyCache
- Application
- DCIM
- media
- Movies
- Musics
- Android

  - data

    - data (I think is not accessible when your are not rooted ???)
    - com.MyDomainName.MyAppName

      - cache
      - files

Then,

2. Following this official Cordova document : http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file
   , My first wish is to store my files and datas with "cordova.file.dataDirectory" or "cordova.file.externalDataDirectory" or another else ... ?
3. when you're doing `console.log(cordova.file.dataDirectory)` you obtain `file:///data/data/com.MyDomainName.MyAppName/files/` => This, you cannot access when you are no rooted
   and when you're doing `console.log(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory)` you obtain 
   `file:///storage/emulated/0/`

and when you're doing that

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
function gotFS(fileSystem) { console.log(fileSystem.root) ...
```

you can see in this object : nativeURL: "file:///storage/emulated/0/" ... so, it's the same like "externalDataDirectory" and I suppose we cannot use "dataDirectory" ...

Anyway, I don't know whether it's the best practice but here you are my solution :

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSWin, getDirectoryFail);

function onFSWin(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("myFolder", {create: true, exclusive: false}, getDirectorySuccess, getDirectoryFail);
}

function getDirectorySuccess(parent) {
    console.log("New Folder or Folder already exists: " + parent.fullPath);
}

function getDirectoryFail(error) {
    console.log("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
}

// Second, we gonna check or create a new file in a specific folder
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSWin2, onFSFail2);

function onFSWin2(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("myFolder/myFile1.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, onFSFail2);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("New file: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, onFSFail2);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {

writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
   console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");

   writer.truncate(11);

   writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
       console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");

       writer.seek(4);
       writer.write(" different text");

       writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
           console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
       }
   };
};
writer.write("some sample text");
}

function onFSFail2(error) {
console.log(error.code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` to use the [`cordova.file.*`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#file-system-layouts) properties:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
    dirEntry.getFile("myFile1.txt", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, function (fileEntry) {
        // fileEntry.createWriter
    }, onError);
});
```